# How to achieve one to many relationships for more than one table in microsoft access for many

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to show 1 record of veterinary history sheet with many records of measurement, a record of movement, lab investigation, vaccination, and inoculation,
Deworming record and Hospital Adm record.

How do you achieve the contents above in `Access`?

[image]

Comment: You are looking for the concept of **subforms**.

Comment: no i commonly want to use viternay history sheet with all other sheets means iit will remain common to all other sheets i am looking for relationship

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat [viternay history sheet].id in all of your other tables rather than pulling the primary key from the tables on the many side. You can and should still have all of the other primary keys, but add an id column to each of the tables and make the relationship between [viternay history sheet].id and [Deworming Record].id, etc. You can remove mea_ID, rma_ID, etc. from [viternay history sheet]

Comment: thanks this i can achieve with lookup wizard in other tables

Comment: Yes, you can use the lookup wizard to show you what you want to see in the other tables, but the table relationships are incorrect for what you are trying to do.